# Switching between tun interfaces without affecting session

Tags: iptables, routing, tunneling

I have two tun interfaces `tun1` and `tun2` with IP addresses `10.0.0.1` and `10.0.0.2` respectively.
I can make applications use these interfaces by binding them to the IP. For example, I can make `iperf3` use `tun1` as follows.

`iperf3 -c <server_ip> -B 10.0.0.1`

Now, while the iperf3 session is active, is it possible to switch to `tun2` i.e., `10.0.0.2`  without affecting the session? The goal here is to switch between the two tunnel interfaces, and the application does not necessarily need to bind to either of these IPs (e.g., a proxy IP would work as well)

Comment: This sounds like a "routing" problem. Read `man ip ip-route`. Routing hint: the "`default`" route is where otherwise unmatched (by any other IP/Netmask route) packets are sent.